# How to start a new thread every x seconds

Tags: ruby, multithreading, schedule

I want to start a new thread every x seconds in Ruby, but wasn´t able to figure it out.

Usually the thread execution takes longer then the x seconds, all I managed was something that starts a new thread after the previous one finished.
So I want to start a new thread after x seconds, now matter how many previous threads are still running.

Any ideas?

Comment: _"all I managed was something that starts a new thread after the previous one finished"_ – include your attempts, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
threads = [] # array of Thread in case you need to do something with all the Threads
             # like threads.each { |t| t.join }

1.upto(5) do |n|
  threads << Thread.new { puts "Thread #{n}!" }
  sleep 1   # or more seconds if need it
end
```